# how to do dependent dropdown by only storing primarykey data that are already related to each other?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I have a table whose data are interconnected with other tables, I want to make a dependent dropdown to store the primarykey id with the selected option related

[

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Ajax Dynamic Dependent Dropdown in Laravel</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.7/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.7/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <style type="text/css">
   .box{
    width:600px;
    margin:0 auto;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <br />
  <div class="container box">
   <h3 align="center">Ajax Dynamic Dependent Dropdown in Laravel</h3><br />
   <form action="{{ url('ajaxRequestPost') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
   {{ csrf_field() }}
   <div class="form-group">
    <select name="unit_kerja" id="unit_kerja" class="form-control input-lg dynamic select2" data-dependent="nama_program">
     <option value="">Select Country</option>
     @foreach($trnpagu as $tp)
     <option value="{{ $tp->unit_kerja}}">{{ $tp->unit_kerja }}</option>
     @endforeach
    </select>
   </div>
   <br />
   <div class="form-group">
    <select name="nama_program" id="nama_program" class="form-control input-lg dynamic select2" data-dependent="nama_kegiatan">
     <option value="">Select State</option>
    </select>
   </div>
   <br />
   <div class="form-group">
    <select name="nama_kegiatan" id="nama_kegiatan" class="form-control input-lg dynamic select2" data-dependent="nama_sub_kegiatan">
     <option value="">Select City</option>
    </select>
   </div>
   <br>
   <div class="form-group">
    <select name="nama_sub_kegiatan" id="nama_sub_kegiatan" class="form-control input-lg dynamic select2" data-dependent="keterangan">
     <option value="">Select City</option>
    </select>
   </div>
   <br>
   <div class="form-group">
    <select name="keterangan" id="keterangan" class="form-control input-lg dynamic select2" data-dependent="uraian_bas">
     <option value="">Select City</option>
    </select>
   </div>
   <br>
   <div class="form-group">
    <select name="uraian_bas" id="uraian_bas" class="form-control input-lg dynamic select2" data-dependent="unit_layanan">
     <option value="">Select City</option>
    </select>
   </div>
   <br>
   <div class="form-group">
    <select name="unit_layanan" id="unit_layanan" class="form-control input-lg dynamic select2" data-dependent="standar_kegiatan">
     <option value="">Select City</option>
    </select>
   </div>
   <br>
   <div class="form-group">
    <select name="standar_kegiatan" id="standar_kegiatan" class="form-control input-lg select2" ">
     <option value="">Select City</option>
    </select>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <button class="btn btn-success " type="submit">Kirim</button>
    </div>
 </form>
   <br />
   <br />
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('.dynamic').change(function(){
  if($(this).val() != '')
  {
   var select = $(this).attr("id");
   var value = $(this).val();
   var dependent = $(this).data('dependent');
   var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
   $.ajax({
    url:"{{ route('dynamicdependent.fetch') }}",
    method:"POST",
    data:{select:select, value:value, _token:_token, dependent:dependent},
    success:function(result)
    {
     $('#'+dependent).html(result);
    }

   })
  }
 });

 $('#unit_kerja').change(function(){
  $('#nama_program').val('');
  $('#nama_kegiatan').val('');
  $('#nama_sub_kegiatan').val('');
  $('#keterangan').val('');
  $('#uraian_bas').val('');
  $('#unit_layanan').val('');
  $('#standar_kegiatan').val('');
 });

 $('#nama_program').change(function(){
  $('#nama_kegiatan').val('');
  $('#nama_sub_kegiatan').val('');
  $('#keterangan').val('');
  $('#uraian_bas').val('');
  $('#unit_layanan').val('');
  $('#standar_kegiatan').val('');
 });

 $('#nama_kegiatan').change(function(){
  $('#nama_sub_kegiatan').val('');
  $('#keterangan').val('');
  $('#uraian_bas').val('');
  $('#unit_layanan').val('');
  $('#standar_kegiatan').val('');
 });

 $('#nama_sub_kegiatan').change(function(){
  $('#keterangan').val('');
  $('#uraian_bas').val('');
  $('#unit_layanan').val('');
  $('#standar_kegiatan').val('');
 });

 $('#keterangan').change(function(){
  $('#uraian_bas').val('');
  $('#unit_layanan').val('');
  $('#standar_kegiatan').val('');
 });

 $('#uraian_bas').change(function(){
  $('#unit_layanan').val('');
  $('#standar_kegiatan').val('');
 });

 $('#unit_layanan').change(function(){
  $('#standar_kegiatan').val('');
 });
 

});
</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.select2').select2();
    });
  </script>
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3F5fA.png)

example: if I select id_unit_kerja = 1 then the second option is id_program = 1 then choose id_kegiatan = 6 then select id_sub_kegiatan only appear = 2,6,8,9 then on id_sub_kegiatan activity select 8 then select id_mak = 3 then select id_bas = 6 then select id_unit_layanan = 2 and in the id_standar_kegiatan there are only choices 75 & 86, we choose id_standar_kegiatan = 86 then the one hided id_trnpagu = 7.
how to keep id_trnpagu = 7 using dependent dropdown
or is there another way?

below this table with fields that are interconnected with other tables

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3F5fA.png)

can you help me to solve this problem?